# Objective-c application plugin quick start

Tags: objective-c, plugins, bundle

I need to add a few methods to an already identified class in a closed source application.  Using f-script anwywhere and gdb I know what I need to interact with to acheive my goals.

However I am struggling to find a solution to allow me to inject some code (preferably objective-c) into the running application.

For the time being I would be quite happy to just inject the code via gdb and manually start the code as I just recently upgraded to Snow leopard and are aware of issues with SIMBL.

Are there any basic guides on getting started with this?  I fail to find anything really useful from googling around.

I think I need to create an application bundle (never done this before so this in itself is a challenge) and use GDB to load into the application.  Once this is done I beleive I can then call my bundles code from GDB.

Basically I think I need some hints on creating the bundle and the subsequent loading via GDB.  Any simple examples of loading a class/object into an application (maybe simply a hello world should suit) would be very much appreciated.

I may also be misguided with the focus on bundles?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use the environment variable `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` to load (plain old dynamic) libraries before loading the main executable. See `man dyld`.

Mike Ash has a [nice article](http://www.mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/friday-qa-2009-01-30-code-injection.html) about easy code injection using gdb.